# Error in Returning Promise ,Getting Error as .then is not a function in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I am getting the error as  **`modifyProduct.then is not a function`**, I have read through some article and it says because I have not returned any promises, How I can achieve this, Can someone help me

Here I am calling `modifyProduct` inside `executionFromCompany` function and then I am using `executionFromCompany` inside the controller

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ["chart.js"]);
 app.factory('ProductsService', function($http) {
     function getProduct() {
         return $http.get('finalmsodetails.json').then(function(response) {
             //console.log(response.data);
             return response.data;
         });
     }

     function modifyProduct() {
         return getProduct().then(function(rawData) {
             newtest = rawData;
             //console.log('test', newtest.length);
             var lightData = rawData.map(function(item) {
                 // use Object.assign to prevent mutating original object
                 var newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
                 var lightExecutions = item.executions.map(function(d) {
                     var ld = {
                         id: d.id,
                         orderId: d.orderId,
                         executionStatus: d.executionStatus,
                         executedOn: d.executedOn,
                         executedBy: d.executedBy,
                         executedByDisplay: d.executedByDisplay,
                     };
                     return ld;
                 });
                 newItem.executions = lightExecutions;
                 return newItem;
             });
             return lightData;
         });
     }

     function executionFromCompany() {
         return modifyProduct.then(function(lightData) {
             executionByCompany = $filter('filter')(lightData.executions, function(inputs) {
                 if ((inputs.executedBy == 'a')) return inputs;
             });
             console.log(executionByCompany);
             return executionByCompany;
         });
     }
     return {
         getProduct: getProduct,
         modifyProduct: modifyProduct,
         executionFromCompany: executionFromCompany
     };
 });
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ProductsService) {
     ProductsService.executionFromCompany().then(function(value) {
         console.log(value);
     }, function(err) {
         // Here will be if there was an error
     })
 });
```

Comment: simple typo error modifyProduct().then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`modifyProduct` is a function, not an object

change this

```
modifyProduct.then
```

to this

```
modifyProduct().then
```

Comment: Thanks !! Can u pls help me how I can  make sure that `modifyProduct` returns value

Comment: you can use callback method to return values

Comment: what makes you think it doesn't return anything?

Comment: Suppose if i am having null values, Just wanted to handle that as well